# Docusaurus getting mermaid up and running

Tags: docusaurus, mermaid

[docusaurus] Newbie question: I am attempting to get mermaid up and running on my website, but am struggling to implement https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/diagrams. My docusaurus.config.js file is structured as follows:

```
const config = {
 ...
 presets: [
  ...
 ],

 themeConfig:
 ({
  ...
 }),

}

module.exports = config;
```

Where should the block

```
 markdown: {
   mermaid: true,
 },
 themes: ['@docusaurus/theme-mermaid'].
```

be included in this structure?

I have attempted to include the stated block at all different points in the config.js file, but I either get a compile fail, or compile succeed, but no mermaid behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now working - I think the issue here was that the project I was attempting to use mermaid on was a 2.1.0 project. Once I updated it to 2.2.0 then things work as the documentation suggests.

Comment: To be clear - the markdown: / themes block is included in the top level of the ``const config =`` block